# MVC. Cant see view after HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following code for the search button on my MasterPage:

```
     <form id="form1" runat="server"> 
        <input type="text" value="Поиск" size="25" class="search-form" id="txt_search" name="txt_search" />
        <button type="submit" name="b_search" id="b_search" value="1" class="but-search"  onclick="javascript:MySaveFunc(txt_search); ">&nbsp</button>  

     <script type="text/javascript">
         function MySaveFunc(rec) {
             var new_name = rec.value;

             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Home/SearchPost',
                 type: "POST",
                 cache: false,
                 data: {
                     txt_name: rec.value 
                 },
                 success: function (data) {

                 },
                 error: function (data) {

                 }
             });


             return false;
         }

</script>
    </form>
```

I also have the following code in my Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
        public  ActionResult  SearchPost(string txt_name)
        {          
           return RedirectToAction("Search", new { txt_name =txt_name });       

        }


        public ActionResult Search(string txt_name)
        {     
            ......

             return View("Search");
        }
```

And in global.asa

```
  routes.MapRoute("Search", "Home/Search/{txt_name}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Search", txt_name = UrlParameter.Optional });
  routes.MapRoute("SearchPost", "Home/SearchPost/{txt_name}", new { controller = "Home", action = "SearchPost", txt_name = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

If i call like this- http://localhost:55419/Home/search/126  - It's works fine.
But if I click on the "Search" button , the application does not show the page "Search"!!

First go to the "SearchPost" action, then "Search". Without errors.  But the last line is not working:

```
 return View("Search");
```

The application does not show view "search", only  the previous page.
What's wrong ?.

Comment: You have the JavaScript function `MySaveFunc` which stops the forms natural submit process and posts via AJAX instead. If you look at the contents of `data` in the success callback the HTML for your rendered view will be in there.

Comment: Ajax calls say on the same page, they do not redirect

Comment: `runat="server"` is Web Forms, not MVC (delete it). `onclick="javascript:MySaveFunc(txt_search);` will pass undefined to you function because `txt_search` is not defined. `return RedirectToAction("Search", new { txt_name =txt_name });` does not work because you are making an ajax call. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I just want to draw search field and button on master page , get search text value and then show search page and result. I dont understand - how can I post value and work in my controller, if submit button is on masterpage?  Thank you

Comment: The code you have shown does not make sense (read my first comment). What do you mean _MasterPage_? (MVC does not have masterpages - do you mean a Layout?) And are you wanting to update the current page with the filtered results based on your search text? - in which case where is the element you want to update?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Im using  ASPX View Engine , instead of - Razor View Engine. So I have master page. My master page have a search field and buttom and 2 ContentPlaceHolders. "Search" button should trigger action in the controller, there is a procedure carried out search of goods, and the result should be shown on the page "Search.aspx". Search works fine, but the page "search" does not show. The application is on the page, which has been before.

Comment: Of course its on the stays in the same page - your making an ajax all (ajax calls do not redirect). If you want to redirect, then do a normal submit (but your not changing data so it should be a FormMethod.Get, not a Post. But if you want to update the current page with the new result, then you need to update the DOM in the ajax `.success()` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
[HttpPost]
public  ActionResult  SearchPost(string txt_name)
{          
    return JavaScript(string.Format("window.location = '{0}'", Url.Action("Search", "Controller"));
}
```

You will have to make sure the url to the `Search` action method is correct, I don't know what the controller name is.

The theory is that since you have made a client-side ajax request, returning `View("Search")` won't work in your case. Instead, return a `JavaScript` action result with a command to redirect the browser to the search page. You can add querystring params to the url, or whatever else you need, to pass to the `Search` action method.

Comment: It does not work consistently. One time - everything works well, other times - not working.Very strange :(